# postfix/dovecot says "postmaster_address setting not given" but it is

Tags: linux, postfix, email-server, dovecot

I'm trying to configure postfix and dovecot to work together with virtual domains stored in MySQL, but I keep running into this whenever mail is passed from postfix to dovecot.

```
Apr 26 11:54:40 smtp postfix/pipe[13165]: 20CCE1C30D5: to=<james@domain.ext>, relay=dovecot, delay=45846, delays=45846/0.28/0/0.14, dsn=4.3.0, status=deferred (temporary failure. Command output: lda: Error: user james@domain.ext: Error reading configuration: Invalid settings: postmaster_address setting not given lda: Fatal: Internal error occurred. Refer to server log for more information. )
```

Now, since I do know how Google works, I found lots of reference to "you need to add the postmaster_address option to the lda protocol line in 15-lda.conf".

It is, here is the output of `doveconf -n`

```
# 2.2.9: /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf
# OS: Linux 3.13.0-49-generic i686 Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS ext4
auth_debug = yes
auth_mechanisms = plain login
auth_verbose = yes
disable_plaintext_auth = no
last_valid_uid = 5000
mail_debug = yes
mail_gid = vmail
mail_location = maildir:/var/mail/virtmail/%d/%n
mail_uid = vmail
managesieve_notify_capability = mailto
managesieve_sieve_capability = fileinto reject envelope encoded-character vacation subaddress comparator-i;ascii-numeric relational regex imap4flags copy include variables body enotify environment mailbox date ihave
namespace inbox {
  inbox = yes
  list = yes
  location = maildir:/var/mail/virtmail/%d/%n
  mailbox Drafts {
    special_use = \Drafts
  }
  mailbox Junk {
    special_use = \Junk
  }
  mailbox Sent {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox "Sent Messages" {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox Trash {
    special_use = \Trash
  }
  prefix =
  separator = /
  subscriptions = yes
  type = private
}
passdb {
  args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf.ext
  driver = sql
}
plugin {
  mail_log_events = delete undelete expunge copy mailbox_delete mailbox_rename
  sieve = ~/.dovecot.sieve
  sieve_dir = ~/sieve
}
postmaster_address = postmaster@piku.xyz
protocols = imap pop3 sieve
service auth {
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth {
    group = postfix
    mode = 0666
    user = postfix
  }
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/dovecot-auth {
    group = postfix
    mode = 0660
    user = postfix
  }
  unix_listener auth-userdb {
    group = vmail
    mode = 0600
    user = vmail
  }
}
ssl_cert = </etc/ssl/private/home.piku.org.uk.crt
ssl_cipher_list = ALL:!LOW:!SSLv2:ALL:!aNULL:!ADH:!eNULL:!EXP:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM
ssl_key = </etc/ssl/private/home.piku.org.uk.key
userdb {
  args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf.ext
  driver = sql
}
protocol imap {
  imap_client_workarounds = delay-newmail
  mail_max_userip_connections = 100
}
protocol pop3 {
  mail_max_userip_connections = 10
  pop3_client_workarounds = outlook-no-nuls oe-ns-eoh
}
protocol lda {
  deliver_log_format = msgid=%m: %$
  mail_plugins = sieve sieve
  postmaster_address = postmaster
  quota_full_tempfail = yes
  rejection_reason = Your message to <%t> was automatically rejected:%n%r
}
```

my */etc/postfix/master.cf* contains this to connect it to dovecot

```
dovecot      unix   -        n      n       -       -   pipe
        flags=DRhu user=vmail:vmail argv=/usr/lib/dovecot/dovecot-lda -d $(recipient)
```

What else can I check to see what is causing this error?

Comment: Tried to change the given value `postmaster_address = postmaster` to email address including the domain part?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I fixed it, but the fix wasn't so obvious.

Having a missing postmaster_address setting was not the actual problem. *dovecot-lda not looking at the correct config file was the actual problem*.

However the deeper problem seems to be this "feature" I randomly came across on Google https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/dovecot/+bug/671065 where

> The `deliver` configuration (LDA) is stored in
>   '/etc/dovecot/conf.d/01-mail-stack-delivery.conf'. This is
>   fundamentally broken because dovecot's `deliver` ignores files
>   included with !include_try and !include. This problem shows up with
>   this error:
>
> ```
> Fatal: postmaster_address setting not given
> ```

And is cured by adding `-c /etc/dovecot/conf.d/01-mail-stack-delivery.conf` to the dovecot-lda command line in *master.cf* (although then you have to make both conf.d and the file itself world-readable so the non-root dovecot-lda can read it, which feels like a horrible hack, rather than an actual solution... but now I have working mail.

I leave this answer here in case there is anyone else using Ubuntu who ends up in this situation. May you spend less time than I did fixing it.

Comment: You can accept your own answer as well and this would make others task much easier in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Better answer for me was to add

```
postmaster_address=postmaster at DOMAIN
```

obviously substituting you actual domain for "DOMAIN" in your

> /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf

and then restarting dovecot

```
service dovecot restart
```

Not my answer... I just found it here:
https://github.com/mail-in-a-box/mailinabox/issues/31
and it fixed my problem.